# How to retrieve Eloquent model with relationship after customized relationship

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have 2 tables with custom Eloquent relationships between the models. The relationship is straight forward with Kredittkort.leverandor_id referencing Bankleverandor.fpid

```
class Bankleverandor extends Model {
protected $primaryKey = 'fpid';
protected $guarded = [];
public function kredittkort() {
    return $this->hasMany("App\Kredittkort", 'leverandor_id', 'fpid');
}}
```

and

```
class Kredittkort extends Model {
protected $guarded    = [];
protected $primaryKey = 'fpid';
public function bankleverandor() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Bankleverandor", "leverandor_id", 'fpid');
}}
```

The relationships work fine. for example

```
Kredittkort::find(258053)->bankleverandor;
Bankleverandor::find(441)->kredittkort;
```

gives me expected results which indicate that relationship is properly defined in Eloquent ORM. However, calling the relationship using "with" clause throws exception

```
RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php line 20:Call to undefined relationship [\App\Bankleverandor] on model [App\Kredittkort].
```

I am trying to retrieve the relationship as follows

```
Kredittkort::with(["\App\Bankleverandor" => function($q) {return $q->select("fpid,orgnr"); }]);
```

I want to understand how can i retrieve the relationship in the above case. If there is another recommended way, then I would love to know that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Kredittkort::with(['bankleverandor' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('fpid','orgnr');
}])->get();
```

Here is a link to the documentation: [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wrongly loading the relationship by using the namespace for the class.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing similar problem. I was wrongly loading the relationship using the fully qualified name of the related class. Instead I should have used the method name (bankleverandor), where I defined the relationship belongsTo.

**wrong usage :**

`Kredittkort::with(["\App\Bankleverandor" => function($q) {
   return $q->select("fpid,orgnr"); 
}]);`

**Correct usage :**

`Kredittkort::with(['bankleverandor' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('fpid','orgnr');
}])->get();`